# Canonical question for “What is this light in the sky?”

Tags: discussion, support, community-wiki

Do we have a good question that we can point to (as a duplicate) for the *I saw this light in the sky* questions, that don't have enough information?. I could not find a good one.

I'm thinking about a question that has answers that can be used as 'determination guides'.

Should we write one? (*How can I identify this light that I saw in the sky?*)
A community wiki?

FWIW: Currently

- [63 questions with 'light in the sky'](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+light+in+the+sky)
- [8 questions with 'strange light'](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+strange+light)
- [9 questions tagged *ufo*](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%5Bufo%5D)

Comment: No need to close as duplicate. If it's a poor question, just close as unclear what you're asking. You can point the user to our help resources which indicate that we have strict requirements for such questions.

Comment: The last point in https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/13489/21 sort of answers this + it may be a good "quick comment" answer for people who don't know it exists?

Comment: If anyone wants to indicate a dupe, this could be it: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/11634/star-like-light-moving-in-the-sky-what-could-it-be

Answer (score 4):

Copying [call2voyage](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/users/6/called2voyage)'s comment:

> No need to close as duplicate. If it's a poor question, just close as unclear what you're asking. You can point the user to our help resources which indicate that we have strict requirements for such questions.

For reference: This is what the [What topics can I ask about](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page says:

> **What about that thing in the sky?**
>
> Avoid asking questions about unidentified aerial objects unless you are prepared to provide detailed pictures and/or sufficient description to identify the time, location, and characteristics of the sighted object. Specifically, this is not a UFO reporting site, but identifying things in the sky is a part of astronomy. If you must ask about that thing in the sky, be prepared to explain a lot and add additional information requested by commenters, or your question may be closed quickly.

Copying from [barrycarter](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/users/21/barrycarter)'s comment under my question:
You may want to leave a comment pointing to [this answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/13489/21) with resources for identification.