# Is this site appropriate for identifying ufos?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, specific-question, questions

I am just asking this question before I post some questions regarding my analysis on a "ufo case on mars" which I think is just I misidentified moon. Because I needed critique of my analysis which involves some photo analysis and math. If this site is not appropriate for such discussion is there an alternative site I can refer to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This site is not a discussion site. It exists to provide answers to well-defined questions that concern astronomy and astrophysics from both an observational and theoretical perspective.

Questions about UFOs could be on topic, but questions like "what is this thing I saw in the sky?" are generally not viewed favourably and usually closed as duplicates of other questions in the same vein (see [Canonical question for “What is this light in the sky?”](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/409/canonical-question-for-what-is-this-light-in-the-sky?rq=1)). Neither are questions like "I have a theory about this picture, am I right?"  which invite discussion - and this is not a discussion site. If you have ideas that you want to test (and they are about astronomy or astronomical observations) then by all means ask about those ideas.

Comment: Well, my question that I want to ask on the Astronomy site boils down to: "Is this "UFO" moving at the same speed as Phobos in the Martian sky". What about I show you the Curiosity picture sequence that shows the "UFO" and then my image analysis to check if the object is moving at the same speed as Phobos in the sky. Could you determine if my analysis would appropriate for this site?

Comment: @spaceamoeba1010 that sounds like a reasonable question.

Comment: And before I start posting on the main Astronomy SE, should I make my questions all in one post, or make it in several posts?

Comment: @spaceamoeba1010 try and keep it to one question at a time.